# Is it possible to use property names that contain periods in Nunjucks variables?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

When I try to render the Nujucks string: `Greeting: {{ bar.text }}` on the following javascript object context via `renderString()`:

```
const foo = {
  'bar.text': 'Hello world'
}
```

I receive the following output: `Template render error: attempted to output null or undefined value`. This issue is resolved when I remove the periods.

Is it possible to use string properties that contain periods when rendering templates in Nunjucks?

Answer (score 1):

`{{ bar.text }}` implies that you have `bar`-object with `text`-prop. So I see two ways to solve it.

1. Use object

```
const foo = {
  bar: {text: 'Hello world'}
}
```

2. Add filter/global function to get value by string `bar.text`

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addFilter('context', function(variable) {
    return this.ctx[variable];
});

var html = env.renderString(`{{ 'bar.text' | context }}`, {'bar.text': 'Hello-world'});
console.log(html);
```